# Android WebView: fixed-position element does not register click events

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have a simple JavaScript back button in the mobile version of my page:

HTML:

```
<a id="back_button" href="#" onclick="history.back(-1)"></a>
```

CSS:

```
#back_button {
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:150;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-image: url('/static/images/buttons/back.png');
    background-size: 40px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

This button works correctly in mobile browsers, and can be seen [here](http://ookmijnbedrijf.nl). In an Android WebView it is positioned correctly, but can't be clicked. Elements underneath it fire click events instead, as if it's not there. I've experimented with using `touchstart` and other events, but that didn't help. I'm assuming this is caused by the `z-index`. How can I get this button to work?

P.S. I'm aware that there's a better way to get "back button" functionality in an Android WebView, but this has to be the solution for now.

Comment: What happens if you change the z-index to 0?

Comment: I need to make sure this button is on top of the other elements on the page.